# How to format values before saving to database in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a User model with Profit field. Profit field is a DECIMAL (11,0) type. I have a masked input on the form which allows user to input something like $1,000. I want to format that value and remove everything except numbers from it so i will have 1000 saved. Here is what i have so far:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :format_values

  private

  def format_values
    self.profit.to_s.delete!('^0-9') unless self.profit.nil?
  end
end
```

But it keeps saving 0 in database. Looks like it is converting it to decimal before my formatting function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
def profit=(new_profit)
  self[:profit] = new_profit.gsub(/[^0-9]/, '')
end
```

Comment: It just mimics the author's RegExp. Trying not to scary him )

Comment: thanks @jdoe i've used your suggestion and it works like i want it.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, this:

```
def format_values
  self.profit.to_s.delete!('^0-9') unless self.profit.nil?
end
```

is pretty much the same as this:

```
def format_values
    return if(self.profit.nil?)
    p = self.profit
    s = p.to_s
    s.delete!('^0-9')
end
```

So there's no reason to expect your `format_values` method to have any effect whatsoever on `self.profit`.

You could of course change `format_values` to assign the processed string to `self.profit` but that won't help because your cleansing logic is in the wrong place and it will be executed *after* `'$1,000'` has been turned into a zero.

When you assign a value to a property, ActiveRecord will apply some type conversions along the way. What happens when you try to convert `'$1,000'` to a number? You get zero of course. You can watch this happening if you play around in the console:

```
> a = M.find(id)
> puts a.some_number
11
> a.some_number = 'pancakes'
 => "pancakes"
> puts a.some_number
0
> a.some_number = '$1,000'
 => "1,000"
> puts a.some_number
0
> a.some_number = '1000'
 => "1000"
> puts a.some_number
1000
```

So, your data cleanup has to take place *before* the data goes into the model instance because as soon as AR gets its hands on the value, your `'$1,000'` will become `0` and all is lost. I'd put the logic in the controller, the controller's job is to mediate between the outside world and the models and data formatting and mangling certainly counts as mediation. So you could have something like this in your controller:

```
def some_controller
    fix_numbers_in(:profit)
    # assign from params as usual...
end

private

def fix_numbers_in(*which)
    which.select { |p| params.has_key?(p) }.each do |p|
        params[p] = params[p].gsub(/\D/, '') # Or whatever works for you
    end
end
```

Then everything would be clean before ActiveRecord gets its grubby little hands on your data and makes a mess of things.

You could do similar things by overriding the `profit=` method in your model but that's really not the model's job.

Comment: i know i can do that in controller, but i was hoping to automate that process before saving in model itself, since i am calling it from different places. Any ideas?

Comment: thanks for the informative answer btw, and a catch with to_s method in a wrong place.

Answer (score 1):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :format_values

  private

  def format_values
    self.profit = profit.to_s.gsub(/\D/,'') if profit
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def format_values
    self.profit.to_d!
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to write custom setter for this particular instance variable @profit:

```
class User
  attr_accessor :profit

  def profit= value    
    @profit = value.gsub(/\D/,'')
  end
end

u = User.new
u.profit = "$1,000"
p u.profit # => "1000"
```

Comment: I guess `u.profit` returns the instance variable's value. It's a pitfall what you made!

Comment: What do you mean? attr_accessor defines two methods - getter and setter, profit method returns the instance variable's value, that right) Where is a pitfall?)

Comment: Your `User` has nothing to do with `ActiveRecord::Base`. And event if it had, the `@pofit` variable would have nothing to do with `profit` DB attribute. After inheriting your version of `User` from `ActiveRecord::Base` you should have replaced `@profit = ` with `self.profit =`. Otherwise you wold mask the `profit` attribute.

Comment: Redefining setter is about Ruby classes, inherited from ActiveRecord::Base or not. But I think you are right and I should gave an example about Rails, thanks for a good advice)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the rails helper of number with precision. Below is some code.

Generic Example:

```
number_with_precision(111.2345, :precision => 1, :significant => true)     # => 100
```

Rails code Example:

```
def profit=(new_profit)
  number_with_precision(self[:profit], :precision => 1, :significant => true)
end
```